# Multiple file download in one time with Asp.net (without files zipping)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, download

In other word I want to allow the user to download all selected files in one time (whitout create a zip) 
but i would be that user choose time the location to save the file and confirm download only one (not for each file)

I have a grid with a list of files on the server.
I want to implement a Multiple file download with this target:
- user check many file on the grid
- user click only one time a button for downloading
- download starting and each files is download separately ()

i can't use a "For Each" loop to cycle through the list to download each file in sequence, because it cause multiple popup for download confirmation.
i find this JQuery plug-in: http://biesiad.github.com/multiDownload/ but it doesn't work like i want because cause multiple popup open.

I see in an old site that this feature was made with an activex ... but i hope that now that are other way to replicate this feature...

Can you help me ??

Anyway if the only way is integrate an activex, there is one free ?

Answer (score 1):

The zip is the easiest option, as you are essentially sending a user to a new "page" which is the zip, forcing the browser to kick off a download process.

Other ways to do this:

1. Add some non-HTML bits (Java, ActiveX, Silverlight, Flash) to the page that will handle the download management
2. Open multiple "pages", one for each document
3. Use HTML5

Since you do not like option 2 (the JQuery way), you are likely stuck with #1 or #3. The cons of #1 is the user's browser might not support the technology.

- User might have Java off, so Java is not a sure fire option
- User has ActiveX off by default, and it is not universal (worst option in the list IMO)
- User might not have Silverlight installed (fortunately, it will kick off the installer, but if they refuse you have to have another way - maybe "install Silverlight or I will open 1 popup for each file, or I can zip it for you")
- User might not have flash installed (less likely in end users, but possible)

How about #3? Download not well supported in browsers, so you lose your audience unless you can control the browser.

The point here is the only ways I know are zip, extra HTML/JavaScript programming embedded in the browser, multiple popups and HTML5 download.